# Query With Projection In MongoDB, PHP Syntax?

Tags: mongodb, php-mongodb

What is the php syntax which will do the work which the following mongodb Shell does?

```
> db.SoManySins.find({},{"_id":0,"FactoryCapacity":1})
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The MongoDB PHP driver functions are named similar to their shell counterparts, so in this case you would be using [MongoCollection::find()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.find.php).  The PHP driver uses associative arrays to map fields to MongoDB queries.

Since the PHP `MongoCollection::find()` documentation page doesn't currently include an example with projection, I've added one below for completeness:

```
<?php
    $m = new MongoClient();
    $db = $m->selectDB('test');
    $collection = new MongoCollection($db, 'SoManySins');

    // Search criteria
    $query = array();

    // Projection (fields to include)
    $projection =  array("_id" => false, "FactoryCapacity" => true);

    $cursor = $collection->find($query, $projection);
    foreach ($cursor as $doc) {
        var_dump($doc);
    }
?>
```

For the projection spec you can use 1/0 (include/exclude) as in the `mongo` shell, or equivalent true/false constants.

It's well worth working through the [Tutorial](http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.tutorial.php) in the PHP MongoDB driver documentation as well as viewing some of the [archived presentations](http://www.10gen.com/presentations?application=All&programming_lang=109&speaker=&event=&language=All) on the 10gen web site.

Comment: Turned out it was the way the collection is made up, I was missing that.  All the old documentation  ( the stuff which shows up on page 2 and 3 + of a Google search? Oh yeah, useful. Hope it never goes away. ) Right, well with the example above, I got the script working in a very few minutes.  Here's another feather AND a bead!

Comment: Note: The new PHP extension [``mongodb``](http://php.net/manual/en/set.mongodb.php) has a different API from the old deprecated [``mongo``](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mongo.php) PHP extension.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using [MongoDB driver](http://php.net/manual/en/set.mongodb.php) conjunction with the  [MongoDB PHP library](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-library)

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php'; // include Composer's autoloader

$client = new MongoDB\Client("mongodb://localhost:27017");

$result = $client->your_database_name->SoManySins->find(array(),array('projection' =>array('_id'=>FALSE,'FactoryCapacity' => TRUE)));

foreach ($result as $entry){
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($entry);
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

Comment: it should be mentioned first that I love this reply, but more importantly it now does not allow TRUE and FALSE values for Projections. can only be of one value type, Truthy or Falsy not both.````'MongoDB\\Driver\\Exception\\CommandException: Projection cannot have a mix of inclusion and exclusion````